# Решение для access-control-allow-origin на клиенте

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

Добрый день. Открываю HTML файл с локального компа. Файл должен слать ajax запрос до некоего API и реагировать на него. Но в результате я получаю

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Проблему надо решить на клиенте. Запустить веб сервер нет возможности.

Если нет решений для кода, предложите браузер, который это пропустит. Нужно, чтобы файл работал в винде, на iOS и на андроиде.

Comment: берете трейтий сервер. реализуете там скрипт, который шлет аналогичный запрос средствами пхп. настраиваете на нем CORS и в своем html уже обращаетесь не к тому АПИ, а к своему скрипту. других вариантов под сразу 3 ОС вы вряд ли найдете

Comment: это если под "запустить вэб-сервер" вы имели  в виду локальный.

Comment: @teran, а без третьего сервера совсем никак? Некий сайт предлагает АПИ. Некоторую информацию мне необходимо показывать одному человеку, при этом не давая свои учетные данные. Я не хочу для этого платить за хостинг или выделенный сервер.